how to proxy http://xxx/pic/ to a docker 127.0.0.1:8888/
I have installed a picture service named Picsur with docker image. It works fine at  http://127.0.0.1:8888. I have only one FQDN host http://www.example.com/.  I can't configure a name-based host like http://pic.example.com/ to service the picture service . So i decide to configure nginx reverse proxy like this:
http://www.example.com/pic/  -->  http://127.0.0.1:8888
My nginx configuration like this :
server {
    listen  443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/p_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/p_error.log;
    error_page 404  /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    
    location / {
        root /data/www/portal;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /pic {
        rewrite ^/pic/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    }
}  

I can't adapted the url inside the picsur docker. So the resources in the page inside like /assets/css/xxx.css are not rewrite to /pic/assets/css/xxx.css. The reverse proxy are not working like what i want.
I have read some post like this. But they can adapt the blog config to alter the url to /blog/ . But i don't want to adapt the docker config.  How can i change the nginx proxy config?

